# ZeroMQ: How to get the address of the connected clients?

Tags: authentication, client, authorization, identity, zeromq

When I use regular UDP sockets, I get the address of the remote client from recvfrom().
When I use regular TCP sockets, I get the address of the remote client as part of calling accept().
However, in ZeroMQ, there seems to be no good way of getting the address of the remote client.
If I want to use this for accepting requests from generally untrusted third parties on the internet, then this is highly inconvenient, as there would for example be no way for me to filter which remote nodes would be allowed to subscribe on a particular publisher socket.

What am I missing? Is ZMQ only really suitable for use on a firewall protected LAN / VLAN? A simple "source address" metadata field on each message would for example be pretty useful, as would some way to register a "gatekeeper" that allows or disallows connections on bound sockets.

Note that the "IDENTITY" option on a socket does not solve this problem, as it is trivially spoofable by any source. The source IP/port is by contrast NOT spoofable, if the remote entity wants to get any packets back in response.

Comment: If you need to filter/block untrusted parties, use a firewall or router device; avoid putting that logic in application code. Zeromq does not provide physical client IP's, see this http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.network.zeromq.devel/9896

Comment: This means that ZeroMQ cannot be used as the transport for a distributed application. I couldn't write an IM client, or a game server, using ZeroMQ as the messaging fabric.

Comment: Yes you can, chat/game clients connect to middleware first where they get a unique client id (you can set this), zeromq can route messages to individual clients with ROUTER sockets using these ids, you'll find examples in zeromq demonstrating chat server; you can do it without a server too, search around.

Comment: The unique client ID for a socket is only documented for a request/response socket. It's also not provided with the actual message I receive, so I don't see how to tie it to an authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but let me give my input, since I've come across this issue as well.

My clients authenticate (and encrypt) by their CURVE keys.  However it seems that once a client's public key is added to the server (zmq.AuthCurveAdd) everything is done under the hood and hidden from the developer.  Meaning, I know my clients are authorized to the server (because they have a keypair that the server trusts), but I don't know who's who.  The same issue exists with identity, as you've mentioned above.  I have to trust that my clients are who they say they are.

I maintain the key authentication / encryption, as well as identity, but add another layer for better authentication (tying a given message to a particular client): the client stores its identity in a configuration file, the server has it in an SQL table next to a password hash.  The client sends its identification with each message (of course), and also the hash of its password.  Simple, but it works.

Now what I need to do is use an HMAC / something similar, so that I rely on more than just the hash for authentication.  But you can see what I'm getting at (that I had to design my own solution on top of ZMQ).